# selenium scrolling and clicking loop

Tags: python, facebook, selenium, scroll

The following code scrolls and searches for the "Like" button and clicks it.

I Want to press the "like" button for having an attribute: `a.find_element_by_css_selector("span#like-button.btn.btn-default.stat-item")`.

However, upon execution, the script scrolls, likes the first, sometimes 2 posts, and scrolls. The code is taken from the open source FB autoliker and edited.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common import exceptions
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


class FacebookBot:
    def __init__(self,username,password,status_report=False):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password

        self.status_report = status_report

        options = Options()
        options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")

        if self.status_report: print("Opening chromedriver...")
        self.wd = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
        if self.status_report: print("Logging in...")
        self.login()

    def login(self):
        self.wd.get("https://hiall.app")
        self.wd.find_element_by_name("username").send_keys(self.username)
        self.wd.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys(self.password)
        self.wd.find_element_by_css_selector("button.btn.btn-main").click()

    def convert_to_int(self,string):
        try:
            return int(string)
        except ValueError:
            if string.lower().endswith("k"):
                string = string[:-2]
                try:
                    return int(float(string)*1000)
                except ValueError:
                    return int(string)*1000

    def get_posts(self):
        articles = self.wd.find_elements_by_css_selector("span#like-button.btn.btn-default.stat-item")
        data = []
        for a in articles:
            if a.get_attribute("id").startswith("span#like-button.btn.btn-default.stat-item"):
                likeIts = [i.get_attribute("aria-label").split() for i in a.find_elements_by_css_selector("span#like-button.btn.btn-default.stat-item") if i.get_attribute("aria-label")]
                likes = {"Like":0,"Love":0,"Haha":0,"Wow":0,"Sad":0,"Angry":0}
                likes.update({i[1]: self.convert_to_int(i[0]) for i in likeIts})
                try:
                    button = a.find_element_by_css_selector("span#like-button.btn.btn-default.stat-item")
                except exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
                    continue
                data.append({"likes":likes,"button":button,"article":a})
        return data

    def scroll(self,page_end=100):
        find_elem = None
        scroll_from = 0
        scroll_limit = self.wd.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
        i = 0
        while not find_elem:
            self.wd.execute_script("window.scrollTo(%d, %d);" % (scroll_from, scroll_from + scroll_limit))
            scroll_from += scroll_limit
            i += 1
            if page_end and i >= page_end:
                break
            try:
                find_elem = self.wd.find_element_by_css_selector("span#like-button.btn.btn-default.stat-item")
                find_elem.click()
            except exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException:
                find_elem = None
            except exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
                find_elem = None

    def automate(self,unlike=False,page_end=100):
        if self.status_report: print("Forcing Facebook to load the posts...")
        self.scroll(page_end)
        if self.status_report: print("Scrolled down %s times" % page_end)
        if self.status_report: print("%s posts..." % ("Unliking" if unlike else "Liking"))
        self.wd.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,0);")
        posts = self.get_posts()
        num = 0
        for p in posts:
            if p["likes"]["Angry"] == 0 and p["likes"]["Sad"] == 0 and p["likes"]["Like"] >= 5:
                article = p["article"]
                self.wd.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", article)
                button = article.find_element_by_css_selector("span#like-button.btn.btn-default.stat-item")
                if true: 
                #button.get_attribute("aria-pressed") == ("true" if unlike else "false"):
                    num += 1
                    self.wd.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",button)
                    try:
                        p = article.find_element_by_tag_name("p").get_attribute("innerText")
                        p = p.replace("\n"," ").encode().decode("utf-8")
                    except exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
                        p = ""
                    except:
                        p = ""
                    if self.status_report: print(' - %s "%s"' % ("Unliked" if unlike else "Liked",p))
        if self.status_report: print("%s %s posts" % ("Unliked" if unlike else "Liked",num))

    def close(self):
        self.wd.close()


username = "whatl0ol"
password = "tornike123"

pages = False
while pages is False:
    inp = input("How many pages to go through? (default 100, 'all' for whole News Feed): ")
    if inp.isdigit():
        pages = int(inp)
    elif inp == "all":
        pages = None

unlike = None
while unlike is None:
    inp = input("Do you want to Like (l) or Unlike (u) posts? ")
    if inp == "l":
        unlike = False
    elif inp == "u":
        unlike = True

bot = FacebookBot(username,password,status_report=True)

bot.automate(unlike=unlike, page_end=pages)
print("Finished")
print()

input("Return to exit")
try:
    bot.close()
except:
    pass
```

Comment: Scrapping [_Facebook_](https://www.facebook.com/) is against the [_ToS 3.2_](https://www.facebook.com/legal/terms) and you are liable to be questioned and may even land up in [_Facebook Jail_](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=804287426255468). Use [**`Facebook Graph API`**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api) instead.

Comment: You probably want to use a webdriverwait to find the elements.. also consider stale element exceptions... btw, the last time I used my own auto-liker they didn't seem to care... but auto-posting to all my friend's timelines caused an issue after about 15 or so.  They didn't jail me, but instead thought my account had been hacked and marked the posts as spam.